# DataFrame empty mysteriously - but why?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there something special about creating a DataFrame with strings that makes it not actually take the values? I'm at a loss as to how to even troubleshoot this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'
df['Feb Total'] = '=SUM(C2:C32)'
... 
df['Yearly Total'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)'
df['Total in Gallons'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172'

print(df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Jan Total, Feb Total, Mar Total, April Total, May Total, June Total, July Total, Aug Total, Sep Total, Oct Total, Nov Total, Dec Total, Yearly Total, Total in Gallons]
Index: []
```

Comment: it assigns value to existing rows but you don't have any rows. You have to create at least one row to assign values - ie. `df['Jan Total'] = ['=SUM(B2:B32)']`.

Comment: @furas said it perfectly

Comment: BTW if you will have many rows then `df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'` will assign this value to all cells in column. ie. `df = pd.DataFrame([[],[]])` `df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'` will put `'=SUM(B2:B32)'` in two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code

```
df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'
```

tries to replace values in all existing cells in column `'Jan Total'` but you don't have rows so it can't replace them. It doesn't create new row.

You can assign value(s) using list

```
df['Jan Total'] = ['=SUM(B2:B32)']

df['Jan Total'] = ['=SUM(B2:B32)', 'value in second row']
```

You can also create DataFrame with row and then replace values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[]])

df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'

df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'
df['Feb Total'] = '=SUM(C2:C32)'
... 
df['Yearly Total'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)'
df['Total in Gallons'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172'

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Jan Total     Feb Total  Yearly Total       Total in Gallons
0  =SUM(B2:B32)  =SUM(C2:C32)  =SUM(B2:M32)  =SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172
```

But if you have more rows - `pd.DataFrame([[], []])` - then it will replace it in all rows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[], []])

df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'

df['Jan Total'] = '=SUM(B2:B32)'
df['Feb Total'] = '=SUM(C2:C32)'
... 
df['Yearly Total'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)'
df['Total in Gallons'] = '=SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172'

print(df)
```

Result

```
      Jan Total     Feb Total  Yearly Total       Total in Gallons
0  =SUM(B2:B32)  =SUM(C2:C32)  =SUM(B2:M32)  =SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172
1  =SUM(B2:B32)  =SUM(C2:C32)  =SUM(B2:M32)  =SUM(B2:M32)/0.264172
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Incidentally, the fix also works if you just make the FIRST one a list. I put brackets around the string for January and voila - all of the subsequent ones worked because I had then established a row in that column.